# How to compare file on local PC and github?

Tags: powershell, github, string-comparison

I have a file on my PC called  `test.ps1`

I have a file hosted on my github called  `test.ps1`

both of them have the same contents  `a string` inside them

I am using the following script to try and comapare them:

```
$fileA = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.ps1"

$fileB = (Invoke-webrequest -URI "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/repo/Scripts/test.ps1")

if(Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $fileA -DifferenceObject ($fileB -split '\r?\n'))

 {"files are different"}

Else {"Files are the same"}

echo ""

Write-Host $fileA

echo ""

Write-Host $fileB
```

however my output is showing the exact same data for both but it says the files are different. The output:

```
files are different

a string

a string
```

is there some weird EOL thing going on or something?

Comment: What's the output of `Compare-Object`?

Comment: ...or an encoding issue? I would first compare the length of the files and then check the first fee bytes and fee bytes with a hex editor.

Comment: As an aside: Since you're only interested in the _text_ of the file you're downloading, a simpler alternative that returns the text _directly_ is to use the [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) cmdlet instead of [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**

```
# Remove a trailing newline from the downloaded file content
# before splitting into lines.
# Parameter names omitted for brevity.
Compare-Object  $fileA  ($fileB -replace '\r?\n\z' -split '\r?\n' )
```

If the files are truly identical (save for any character-encoding and newline-format differences, and whether or not the local file has a trailing newline), you'll see *no* output (because [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) only reports *differences* by default).

---

If the lines *look* the same, it sounds like character encoding is *not* the problem, though it's worth pointing out that [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) in *Windows PowerShell*, in the absence of a BOM, assumes that a file is ANSI-encoded, so a UTF-8 file *without BOM* that contains characters outside the ASCII range will be *misinterpreted* - use `-Encoding utf8` to fix that.

Assuming that the files are truly identical (including *not* having variations in whitespace, such as trailing spaces at the end of lines), the likeliest explanation is that the file being retrieved *has a trailing newline*, as is *typical* for text files.

Thus, if the downloaded file has a trailing newline, as is to be expected, **if you apply `-split '\r?\n'` to the multi-line string representing the entire file content** in order to split it into lines, **you'll end up with an *extra, empty array element* at the end**, which causes [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) to report that element as a difference.

`Compare-Object` emitting an object is evaluated as `$true` in the implied Boolean context of your `if` statement's conditional, which is why `files are different` is output.

The above `-replace` operation, `-replace '\r?\n\z'` (`\z` matches the very end of a (multi-line) string), compensates for that, by removing the trailing newline before splitting into lines.